# When I play my 3 tracks they overlap on each other, how can i pause track1 when I play track2?

Tags: javascript

This is my code for JavaScript, what should I use to stop my tracks overlapping?

```
    let track1 = document.getElementById("track1");    
    let icontrack1 = document.getElementById("icontrack1");

    icontrack1.onclick = function (){
        if(track1.paused){
            track1.play();
            icontrack1.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pause-circle fa-5x"></i>';
        }
        else{
            track1.pause();
            icontrack1.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i>';
        }
    }

    let track2 = document.getElementById("track2");
    let icontrack2 = document.getElementById("icontrack2");

    icontrack2.onclick = function (){
        if(track2.paused){
            track2.play();
            icontrack2.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pause-circle fa-5x"></i>';
        }
        else{
            track2.pause();
            icontrack2.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i>';
        }
    }

    let track3 = document.getElementById("track3");
    let icontrack3 = document.getElementById("icontrack3");

    icontrack3.onclick = function (){
        if(track3.paused){
            track3.play();
            icontrack3.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pause-circle fa-5x"></i>';
        }
        else{
            track3.pause();
            icontrack3.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i>';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Play what you want to hear **and pause others**.

```
let track1 = document.getElementById("track1");    
let track2 = document.getElementById("track2");
let track3 = document.getElementById("track3");
let icontrack1 = document.getElementById("icontrack1");
let icontrack2 = document.getElementById("icontrack2");
let icontrack3 = document.getElementById("icontrack3");

function playTrack(trackNum) {
    var track = document.getElementById("track"+String(trackNum))
    var icontrack = document.getElementById("icontrack"+String(trackNum))
    track.play();
    icontrack.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pause-circle fa-5x"></i>';
    else {
        track.pause();
        icontrack.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i>';
    }
}

function pauseTrack(trackNum) {
    var track = document.getElementById("track"+String(trackNum))
    var icontrack = document.getElementById("icontrack"+String(trackNum))
    track.pause();
    icontrack.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i>';
}

icontrack1.onclick = function (){
    if(track1.paused){
        playTrack(1);
        pauseTrack(2);
        pauseTrack(3);
    }
    else{
        pauseTrack(1);
    }
}



icontrack2.onclick = function (){
    if(track2.paused){
        playTrack(2);
        pauseTrack(1);
        pauseTrack(3);
    }
    else{
        pauseTrack(2);
    }
}



icontrack3.onclick = function (){
    if(track3.paused){
        playTrack(3);
        pauseTrack(1);
        pauseTrack(2);
    }
    else{
        pauseTrack(3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function stopAllTracksExcept(id) {
    // Récupère toutes les pistes et les icônes
    const tracks = document.querySelectorAll("audio");
    const icons = document.querySelectorAll(".fa");

    // Parcours toutes les pistes et icônes et arrête tout sauf la piste avec l'ID donné
    tracks.forEach(function(track) {
        if (track.id !== id) {
            track.pause();
        }
    });
    icons.forEach(function(icon) {
        if (icon.parentElement.id !== "icon" + id) {
            icon.className = "fa fa-play-circle fa-5x";
        }
    });
}

let track1 = document.getElementById("track1");    
let icontrack1 = document.getElementById("icontrack1");

icontrack1.onclick = function (){
    if(track1.paused){
        stopAllTracksExcept("track1"); // Arrête toutes les autres pistes sauf celle-ci
        track1.play();
        icontrack1.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pause-circle fa-5x"></i>';
    }
    else{
        track1.pause();
        icontrack1.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i>';
    }
}

let track2 = document.getElementById("track2");
let icontrack2 = document.getElementById("icontrack2");

icontrack2.onclick = function (){
    if(track2.paused){
        stopAllTracksExcept("track2"); // Arrête toutes les autres pistes sauf celle-ci
        track2.play();
        icontrack2.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pause-circle fa-5x"></i>';
    }
    else{
        track2.pause();
        icontrack2.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i>';
    }
}

let track3 = document.getElementById("track3");
let icontrack3 = document.getElementById("icontrack3");

icontrack3.onclick = function (){
    if(track3.paused){
        stopAllTracksExcept("track3"); // Arrête toutes les autres pistes sauf celle-ci
        track3.play();
        icontrack3.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pause-circle fa-5x"></i>';
    }
    else{
        track3.pause();
        icontrack3.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i>';
    }
}
```

Comment: To help future visitors, could you explain how this fixes the problem?